# Cannot delete Azure Function slot

Tags: azure-functions

I would like to delete an Azure Function deployment slot that is connected to an Elastic Premium app service plan. However, I can't seem to delete the slot.

When trying to manually delete it using the Azure CLI I receive the following error: `'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Precondition Failed'`. In the Azure portal it just simply says 'Failed to delete slot *name*'.

I have no idea what's going on. Can anyone help? :)

UPDATE: This is the  full response: `"Code":"PreconditionFailed","Message":"This slot has TestingInProduction rules and receives some production traffic and cannot be deleted."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your error, you only need to set `TRAFFIC` to `0`. After making changes, please don't forget to click `Save`.

[image]

Then you can use this command to delete it successfully:

```
az functionapp deployment slot delete --name <your-functionapp-name> --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --slot <slot-name>
```